# Which directory of my PHP webapp should I publish on git?

Tags: php, git, version-control

I am working on a PHP webapp. I have to publish it on a distributed version control system (git) but I am not sure wether if to publish the root directory of the project or the public_html folder.

The root folder contains composer-related files and configuration files.

Also, what are the best practices to include the config files, which have to be omitted/obscured from the version control?

The project is structured as follows:

```
+ root
|_ (...)
|_ config.php
|_ composer.json
|_ composer.lock
|_ public_html
    |_ index.php
    |_ (...) // The rest of the project
```

Comment: You would want to commit your `composer.*` files too, right? So the root. As for config files: use https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv

Comment: @brombeer I'm going to give an unfashionable opinion: environment variables are global state, which feels like a step backwards from something scoped to a startup script; and if you have a `.env` file, you might as well just have a `config.ini` or `config.php`, and put it in `.gitignore` if you don't want to commit it. In fact, I think `.env` files violate the spirit of the original 12-factor manifesto, missing the point it was originally trying to make.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

git isn't primarily about "publishing" anything, it's about *tracking the changes* to something, and having somewhere to retrieve particular versions.

It's probably easier to think about what *not* to put into version control:

- Data and application state. You don't want to update your git repository every time someone makes a new comment on your blog, or changes the price of a product on your store.
- Large objects. Git is optimised for small text files; you can put some images in there, like logos and buttons, but probably don't want full-resolution desktop backgrounds, or installers for some piece of software to download. There are solutions like [git-lfs](https://git-lfs.com/) if you need them, but most of the time such "assets" belong somewhere else, like AWS S3 (which has its own versioning).
- Sensitive data. Anyone who has access to the repo has access not just to the current version of the files, but *every previous version*; so you want to be careful to *never* store any passwords or secret keys there.
- Per-deployment configuration. This one gets more fuzzy - some configuration is useful to have versioned, so that you can re-deploy the application without lots of manual setup; but other things should be generated by a setup script. It's hard to answer whether `config.php` should be committed without knowing what's in it - possibly it should be, but some of the things in it should be moved elsewhere.

To *not* commit something, just [list it in `.gitignore`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore). (Note that this isn't a *security* measure, just *convenience*: it doesn't remove already committed files, even them from *future* revisions, nor does it *prevent* you adding them accidentally in future; it just makes most commands not *default* to adding them. You still have to pay attention to what you're committing.)

Everything else probably belongs in git, [including `composer.lock`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#commit-your-composer-lock-file-to-version-control).

Comment: Great answer! One note about `.gitignore`, though, is that it doesn't un-track files you've already added to the repo. (SO many questions about that.)

Comment: A configuration file containing private keys should be committed (empty) as an example? Also, do you have any example/resource on setup scripts?

Comment: @JimRedmond True; I've expanded the caveat of what it *doesn't* do.

Comment: @vale There are a thousand different ways to manage configuration. How you separate the different parts of your configuration, and where you put the parts that you _don't_ want to be in version control, are about how you structure your application, not really to do with git. There's a thousand ways to do it, and this isn't the place to discuss them.